# Delay displayed text in div after keyframe animation

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a keyframe that expands a div's height and width then fades-in the text inside after a delay[when the expansion animation finishes]. The code below shows a button and div that is hidden [display: none] until the button is clicked which displays the div and expands from left to right of the page.

```
<div class="options">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="aboutMe" onclick="showAM()">AboutMe</button>

</div>

 <div class="details">
            <div id="amDiv" class="expandedDetail">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
</div>
```

```
.details{
    border: 1px dotted darkcyan; 
    position: relative; 
    display: flex;
    top: 35%;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
}
.expandedDetail{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 15px;
    outline: dotted yellow;
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    animation: box-expand, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 1s, 2s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 0s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes box-expand{
    from{
        background-color: green;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0%;
    }
    to{
        width: 1700px;
        height: 500px;
        display: block;
        background-color: green;
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}
@keyframes fade-in{
    from{
        opacity: 0%;
        
    }
    to{
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}
```

The box expands the way I want but the problem is that the text within this element can be seen shifting around as the box expands to full size. Ideally, I'd want the text to fade-in after the box animation is finished but can't seem to find a way to hide the text then display with keyframe animations

Thank you for taking the time to read and appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.delay{
  animation: delay 2s ease;
}
@keyframes delay {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*u don't need to use this code*/
div{
  background-color:#342333;
  color:#fff;
  padding:40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="delay">Hi this is the Delay text</p>
</div>
```